# Flexbox row is not scrolling when I scroll the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have built a Netflix row using Flexbox. I can scroll through the row only if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + mouse scroll and when I use the developer tool.

But I want to be able to scroll/slide through the row when I do mouseover/mouse scroll. Like if mouseover on the row, I'll be able to slide the row/scroll through it. So how can I achieve that?

Here is my .jsx file:

```
<div className="row">
  { /* Title */ }
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  <div className="row-posters">
    { /* Several row posters */ }
    {movies.map((movie) => {
      return (
        <img
          key={movie.id}
          onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
          src={`${baseUrl}${
            isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
          }`}
          alt={movie.name}
          className={`row-poster ${isLargeRow && "row-posterLarge"}`}
        />
      );
    })}
  </div>
  {trailerUrl && <Youtube videoId={trailerUrl} opts={opts} />}
</div>;
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.row{
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.row-posters{
    display: flex;
    flex: row;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.row-posters::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}

.row-poster{
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
    transition: transform 450ms;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    counter-increment: row-poster;
}

.row-poster:hover{
    transform: scale(1.08);
}

.row-posterLarge{
    max-height: 250px;
}

.row-posterLarge:hover{
    transform: scale(1.09);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is an image of my row.

[image: JavaScript]

Comment: add stackblitz example please

Answer (score 0):

You can't scroll on a flexible element. One way is wrap 'row-posters' inside 'row-posters-container' element and give styles to that element with

```
<div className="row">
  {/* title */}
  <h2>{title}</h2>
<div className="row-posters-container">
  <div className="row-posters">
    {/*  several row posters */}
    ...
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    .row-posters-container {
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
```